# How many solutions does the system have? Why?

Tags: linear-algebra

How can I solve this problem?

Let Z be a 4 x 5 matrix. A basis for the null space of Z is {} where  ≠ . If the system of equations 
(Z^T) =  is consistent, how many solutions does the system have? Justify your answer. *Note: Z^T is Z transpose.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Hint: what does the null space of $Z$ tell you about the rank of this matrix?

Comment: [How to ask a homework question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question).

Answer (score 0):

Try to find first what is the nulity of z^t, and here you dont need actually field also i am assuming it is complex then the solution will be  cardinality of field ^n(z^t).

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0):

At all cases **THE NUMBER OF SOLUTIONS ARE EQUAL TO THE NUMBER OF INFORMATION PROVIDED** and whenever they are equal the system is regarded as being solvable, relate this to your question

Check the number of information, condition on the system to conclude

Answer (score 0):

Let Z be m * n matrix.
From the information provided it is clear that the dimension of Null Space is 1.  And we know that n - r = dim(Null Space). So r = 5-1 = 4. So, the rank of the matrix is 4.

As the matrix is full row rank(r = m) . You can solve it for any right hand side. Do Gaussian Elimination. You will see there is no zero column as the matrix is full row rank. So, there is no condition that is needed to satisfy on the right hand side ( like zero row value must correspond to zero value on right side).  So the number of solution is infinte.